# How to minimise Electron app to macOS dock

Tags: macos, electron, dock

I can't find a way to send my Electron app to the dock; exactly as the orange top left button in every macOS app title bar does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done at each *window* level by calling [`win.minimize()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winminimize):

> `win.minimize()`
>
> Minimizes the window. On some platforms the minimized window will be
> shown in the Dock.

Example of code for the *main process*:

```
// In the main process.
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

// Load a remote URL
win.loadURL('https://github.com')

// Minimize window to the Dock
win.minimize()
```